# How to remove a black border around Graphics3D[Texture[...]]

Tags: graphics3d, textures

So I can create a 2D image that looks like

```
contourplot = 
 ContourPlot[
  Sin[ x/2] Cos[y], {x, -4 π, 4 π}, {y, -4 π, 4 π}, 
  PlotRange -> All, BaseStyle -> 30]
```

[image]

Notice there is no frame around the image as a whole.  Now I want to use this in a 3D plot using the following command

```
backgroundimage = 
  Graphics3D[{Texture[contourplot], 
    Style[Polygon[{{-1000, -500, -500}, {-1000, 500, -500}, {-1000, 
        500, 500}, {-1000, -500, 500}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
     Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]}];
     
     
Show[backgroundimage, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 800, 
 ViewPoint -> {2, -2, .3}]
```

[image]

A black border has been added around the 3D object.  How can I remove this border? Or is there some way to just make it white?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `EdgeForm@None` for your `Polygon`:

```
backgroundimage = Graphics3D[
     {Texture[contourplot],
      Style[{EdgeForm@None,
             Polygon[{{-1000, -500, -500}, {-1000, 500, -500}, {-1000, 500, 500}, 
                      {-1000, -500, 500}}, 
            VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
     },
     Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
     ]}];


Show[backgroundimage, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 800, ViewPoint -> {2, -2, .3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I noticed that even with `EdgeForm` set to None, there is what appears to be a dashed line at the bottom, visible in your image.  I think this is where the `Texture` meets the `Box` surrounding the `Graphics3D`.  I was able to make this go away by replacing `None` with `White`.

Comment: @JasonB That's great you've got what you need :)

Comment: `EdgeForm[]` is more compact.

Comment: @J.M. can't argue with that :)